# Thread safe write files function in Java

Tags: java, android, multithreading

My goal is to implement a function that allow to write on a file asynchronously, a prototype is

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

public void write(final string filename, final string message) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Create file object (if not exist create a new file)
            File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
            // Try to write on that file
            synchronized(lock) {
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
                    fileOutputStream.write(message.getBytes());
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                catch (...) {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Is this function thread-save? It's possible to lock thread write by file, allowing asynchronous writing on different files *(and show a method/pseudocode/code to accomplish this point)*?

Comment: *"Is this function thread-save?"* Unknown. Is there more than one instance of class with the `lock` field? --- *"It's possible to lock thread write by file?"* Yes.

Comment: First of all, your function is not thread-safe because it does not compile. 
 Secondly, Your function is called `read` yet you are writing.  Your name needs to be reflective of what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `lock`i would create an own class, add it as `public static final` and prevent the class from instantiating (make constructor private). That way you make sure that there is always only one object.

> Is this function thread-save?

Yes

> It's possible to lock thread write by file, allowing asynchronous writing on different files?

Yes

Comment: I hope i understand it correctly: You have a thread and that should write to a file but that is not possible because the file is in use. What you are asking now is: is it possible to use that thread to do some other work? Meaning writing to another file while the first file is blocked. Correct? If that is the situation, your thread could create another thread that writes to the second file and so on. But a better approach would be to use [Thread Pools](http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/multi-threading/java-thread-pool-executor-example). Use one thread for one task.

Comment: Sorry if I explained wrong; imagine to have the class `MyWriterClass` that implement `write(final string filename, final string message)` method, so if I call `MyWriterClass.write("serviceLog", "a")` the call will write asynchronously `a` in the `serviceLog` file; if in the meantime another call `MyWriterClass.write("activityLog", "b")` is fired, this call have to wait that the first write ends (and release the lock) to write on `serviceLog` file; so my question is: can this two write be _theoretically_ done at the same time (if, obviously, the calls were made on different files)? If yes, how?

Comment: Ok, i understood. Actually, no, it's not possible. Because if the file is accessed from the first method call and then the second method call is changing the same file, what happens when the first method call ends the writing is, that it will write the old content with the changes from the first method call into the file and that way the changes from the second call are overwritten. I hope it's clear what i mean :)